# javascript stops working after $.mobile.changePage()

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have two pages: index.html and main.html

When i set the main.html page to be the default page of my app, the java script works, but when I set the index.html to be the main one, after the redirect, the javascript on the main.html just stops working.

here is the HTML of the two pages:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.5.0.js"></script>      

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title>
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<style>
    /* App custom styles */
</style>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.0.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true; 
$.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false; 

 function onLoad(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
 }
 function onDeviceReady(){
    // request the persistent file system
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onSuccess, null);
 }


function onSuccess(fileSystem) {       
    fileSystem.root.getFile("kuapodata.xml", null, gotMe, failFile);
}


// se o arquivo não existir
 function failFile(error) {
    $("#formLogin").show();
 }


// se o arquivo existir
function gotMe(fileEntry) {
    $.mobile.changePage("main.html", null, false, false);       
}



</script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad();">

   <div data-role="page" id="page1">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                Header
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" id="formLogin">
            <form id="loginFrm">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <label for="textinputEmail">
                        </label>
                        <input id="textinputEmail" placeholder="email" value="" type="email" />
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <label for="textinputPassword">
                        </label>
                        <input id="textinputPassword" placeholder="senha" value="" type="password" />
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <input value="entrar" type="submit" />
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>


<script>
var xml;



function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("kuapodata.xml", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
}

function gotFileWriter(writer) {
         writer.write(xml);
}

function fail(error) {
    alert(error.code);
}



// ao fazer o login
$("form").submit(function() {
    // chama função que valida usuário
    ValidateUser();
    return false;
});


// verifica se o usuário existe
function ValidateUser(email, password) {
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://********/oauth.aspx',
        data: "email=" + $("#textinputEmail").val() + "&password=" +  $("#textinputPassword").val(),
        success: function(data) {
            // se o usuário existir
            if (data != "false") {
                xml = data;

                // cria o arquivo xml se ainda não existir
                window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);

                // muda o usuário de  página
                $.mobile.changePage("main.html");
            }
            else {
                alert("Dados inválidos. Tente novamente.");
            }
        }
    });
}

</script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

main.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
        <title>PhoneGap</title>


    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
    <style>
        /* App custom styles */
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.5.0.js"></script>  
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.0.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>

$(document).ready(function() {
   alert("yesss");
});





  </script>
  </head>
  <body>

       <div data-role="page" id="page1">
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
                <h3>
                    Header
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" id="main">

            </div>

        </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

jQuery Mobile pulls in remote pages via AJAX. When it does this, it only pulls in the first `data-role="page"` element it finds. This means that anything outside the `data-role="page"` element is discarded.

The best work-around is to put all of your app's JS into a `custom.js` file and include it in the head of every page, this way all the code for your site is always available (to do this you will need to use event delegation).

You can also put the JS for each page inside the `data-role="page"` element so it is grabbed by jQuery Mobile and not just discarded:

```
   <div data-role="page" id="page1">
        <script>
            alert('hello');
        </script>
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                Header
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" id="main">

        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: hey @Jasper in this particular case, I need to execute an phew fucntions only on the main.html page, what is the best way to do this,  put a script tag inside the <div data-role="page" id="page1"> or use some script code to detect the current page and call the functions I need to? if so, do you know where can I find a tutorial abour this? once again, thank you very much for the answer. Helped a lot.

Comment: @ShadowG Use event delegation: `$(document).delegate('#page1', 'pageinit', function () { /*Run code for page1 here*/ });`. This binds to the `document` element but only triggers when the event fires on the `#page1` element. `pageinit` fires once each time a page is initialized. Include this in an external JS file that you include in every document.

Comment: Since I dont have much expirience with the modeling, instead of `$.mobile.changePage("main.html", null, false, false);` I'll user: `$.mobile.changePage("#main", null, false, false);` where  `#main` is the id of my div element that will reaceive the page content and I will bind the `$(document).delegate('#page1', 'pageinit', function () { /*call the function I need to populate with my html*/ });` and do the same for all my other pages?