# JQuery Mobile losing format

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have a problem working with JQuery.

After

```
 $.mobile.changePage(*toPage*);
```

is executed somehow the format of JQueryMobile is lost?

Is there an easy solution to tackle this problem?

Here is my HTML-Code:

```
    <form action="" data-bind=" template:{ 'if': loginVM, data: loginVM }" id="myLogin" data-role="page"> 
                     //Some Code
    </form>
<form action="" data-bind="template: { 'if': startVM, data: startVM }" id="myStart"  data-role="page">
                          //Some Code
    </form>
```

Somehow if the DOM is altered the Style is lost!

Comment: Could this be the answer to your problem?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728736/javascript-stops-working-after-mobile-changepage

Comment: I'm not quiet sure if this helps...

I'll post my HTML-Code so you can see what i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe each page should have a data-role with an id, so:

```
<div data-role="page" id="login">
    <form action="" data-bind=" template:{ 'if': loginVM, data: loginVM }" id="myLogin"> 
       //Some Code
    </form>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="start">
    <form action="" data-bind="template: { 'if': startVM, data: startVM }" id="myStart">
      //Some Code
    </form> 
</div>
```