# jQM - Javascript doesn't work in 'file.html' when use $.mobile.changePage

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm trying to make transition between two .html files using jQM (just for test):

**index.html:**

```
 <script>

  function Go(){
     var url = "go.html?go='123'";
     $.mobile.changePage(url, {transition: "slide"});
  }

 </script>

<body>
   <button onclick='Go();'>Go!</button>
</body>
```

**go.html:**

```
  <script>
$( document ).on("#mainpage", "pageinit", function() {
  // CODE GET URL VARs

   function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,             function(m,key,value) {
    vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
  }

  var go = getUrlVars()['go'];

  alert(go);
});
  </script>
```

The transition works fine, and i see (in the url browser) the variable '**go**' is there (123).

When the translation finish, the alert doesn't work and i have to refresh the page (F5) to see the alert ('**123**'): JAVASCRIPT IN **go.html** DOESN'T WORK.

How can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The scripts you want executed on that page need to be handled on the `pageinit` or `pagechange` event in jQm. Go read the [scripting section](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html) on the jQm docs.

Comment: Did u ever make a tutorial about this? i edited my post (go.html) but can't solve this issue.

Comment: did you look at this question? [javascript stops working after $.mobile.changePage()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728736/)?